# service function firebase getDocs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I am trying to build a firestore get function to fetch data from firestore database, I successfully fetch the data into the console, but I don't know how to return the data, as everytime that returns a promise.

```
export const getJobPostings = async () => {
  const jobPostingsRef = collection(database, "jobPostings");
  const snapShot = await getDocs(jobPostingsRef);
  snapShot.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item.data());
  });
  return snapShot
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you call this asynchronous function, but since you explained that "everytime (it) returns a promise" you are most probably not calling it correctly.

Since an `async` function always return a Promise, You should either use [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) like for example the following:

```
getJobPostings()
.then(snapShot => {
  snapShot.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item.data());
  });
});
```

or call it with `await` within an **asynchronous** function declared with `async`.

```
export const anotherAsyncFunction = async () => {
  const snapShot = await getJobPostings();
  snapShot.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item.data());
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you Renaud, but I don't want to console.log the data, I want to return the fetched data to a variable, how should I do it in this function?

Comment: It's only within `then()` block that you can get the value of the `QuerySnapshot` returned by the function **which returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)**. So **within this block**, assign the value to the variable.

Comment: Hi @Nigel, did you succeed in getting the fetched data as you wish?

Answer (score 0):

Following the thread in [@Renaud Tarnec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3371862/renaud-tarnec) answer, if you want to save the value obtained in a variable you just have to create a variable and assign the value returned by the function, in the case of "getDocs" it brings you a group of elements from a firestore's collection, so you will have to create an array type variable and pass over the response with a foreach to insert the values into said variable, as follows:

```
// let myVar = [] you can also declare the variable outside the function if you want to use the return value elsewhere

getDocs(collection(db, 'jobPostings'))
  .then((response) => {
    let myVar = []
    response.forEach((doc) => {
      myVar.push(doc.data())
    });
    // console.log('My var:', myVar)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  });
```